# How do I test that a ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput has been posted to a CollaborationGroup?

Tags: unit-test, chatter-feed, connect-api, chatter-groups, collaborationgroup

I have a trigger that posts a ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput, but how do I test that this has been posted, and to the correct chattergroup?

I've created the test collaborationgroup in my test method, but I don't know how I can find the related objects to test the feed has been updated.

Thank you.

Edit: Both methods listed in answers seem to work, but the problem now is why the Advanced Apex Superbadge has implement !Test.isRunning() for the method that holds the functionality of posting the chatter feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chatter Announcements are nothing but FeedItem records. You can just query them after creating an announcement in test class

```
SELECT Body,CreatedById,CreatedDate,HasVerifiedComment,NetworkScope,ParentId,Type FROM FeedItem where createdDate=Today and ParentId=:ChatterGroupID
```

> Most Chatter in Apex methods require access to real organization data,
>   and fail unless used in test methods marked @IsTest(SeeAllData=true).

Make sure you mark your test class seeAllData as true.

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_TestingApex.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But firstly, you should never (rarely) use seeAllData as true. The whole point of the test is to test your logic on test data so that when you move your package to a new org, it still passes test.

This feedItem objects seems good, although it also shows Chatter group creation in the feed.

Comment: I'm also confused about whether during a test, apex will be able to see a chatter group if I created it withing the scope of the test method?

Comment: @rna7 check the link I mentioned. You always use seeAllData as true for testing chatter.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across CollaborationGroupFeed object which can use the ParentId field to connect to chatter group.